# UITextView border for each line

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, border, line

I'm developing an application, which has `textView` with bottom borders for each line, I can't find any answers on this question on google and on StackOverflow. So i decided i'll ask a question, i have this textview:[image: My Textview]

and i want it to look like this: [image: Original Textview]

I'm doing it programmatically so please don't give me storyboard examples, Thank you

Comment: Please check this one -> https://github.com/mfoxstudio/MFUnderlinedTextView/

Answer (score 1):

```
var textview:UITextView=UITextView()
for var i:Int = 20 ; i <= Int(textview.frame.size.height) ; i = i + 20 // set 20 you line distance .. change your chooice
{
    let border = CALayer()
    border.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(i), textview.frame.size.width*1.5 , 1.0)
    border.borderWidth = 1.0
    textview.layer.addSublayer(border)
    textview.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Use this code**

```
-(void)setBorderView:(UITextField*)textField
{
    UIView *borderView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    borderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    CGRect frameRectEmail=textField.frame;


    NSLogVariable(textField);
    borderView.layer.borderWidth=1;
    borderView.layer.borderColor=[customColor colorWithHexString:@"8c8b90"].CGColor;
    borderView.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    borderView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;



    UIView *topBorder = [[UIView alloc]init];
    topBorder.backgroundColor = [customColor colorWithHexString:@"1e1a36"];
    CGRect frameRect=textField.frame;
    frameRect.size.height=CGRectGetHeight(textField.frame)/1.5;
    topBorder.frame = frameRect;
      frameRectEmail.size.width=frameRect.size.width;
    [borderView setFrame:frameRectEmail];

    [_textFieldBackGroundView addSubview:borderView];
    [_textFieldBackGroundView addSubview:topBorder];
    [_textFieldBackGroundView addSubview:textField];

}
```